# Ошибка match-case: SyntaxError: name capture 'GAME' makes remaining patterns unreachable

Tags: python, case, match

При попытки запустить код питон сразу выкидывает ошибку не пытаясь даже выполнять код

```py
import random

GAME = 0
PAUSE = 1
SHOP = 2
state = GAME

state = random.randint(0, 2)

match state:
        case GAME:
            print(state)
        case PAUSE:
            print(state)
        case SHOP:
            print(state)
```

> SyntaxError: name capture 'GAME' makes remaining patterns unreachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы будете получать ошибку до тех пор, пока не будете использовать классы

Пример

```py
class State:
    GAME = 0
    PAUSE = 1
    SHOP = 2
```

в случае использования констант в данной конструкции, вам необходимо их соотнести с полями класса. А далее вот так

```py
state = random.randint(0, 2)

match state:
    case State.GAME:
        print(state)
    case State.PAUSE:
        print(state)
    case State.SHOP:
        print(state)
```

Comment: @cucumber спс, криво скопипастил